# Sum on collection invariant prevent Aggregate root creation/update

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I am aware there is a lot of topics on set validation and i won’t say i have read every single one of them but i’ve read a lot and still don’t feel i’ve seen some definite answer that doesn’t smell hackish.

Consider this:

- we have a concept of `Customer`
- `Customer` has some general details data
- `Customer` can make `Transaction` (buying things from the store)
- if `Customer` is in credit mode then he has a limit of how much he can spend in a year
- number of `Transactions` per `Customer` per year can be huge (thousands+)
- it is critical that `Customer` never spents a cent over a limit (there is no human delivering goods that would check limit manually)
- `Customer` can either create new `Transaction` or add items to existing ones and for both the limit must be checked
- `Customer` can actualy be a `Company` behind which there are many `Users` making actual transactions meaning `Transactions` can be created/updated concurrently

Obviously, i want to avoid loading all `Transactions` for `Customer` when creating new or editing existing `Transaction` as it doesn’t scale well for huge number of `Transactions`.

If i introduce aggregate dedicated to check `currentLimitSpent` before create/update `Transaction` then i have non-transactional create/update (one step to check `currentLimitSpent` and then another for create/update `Transaction`).

I know how to implement this if i don’t care about all ddd rules (or if its eventual consistency approach) but i am wondering if there is some idiomatic ddd way of solving this kinds of problems with strict consistency that doesnt involve loading all `Transactions` for every `Transaction` create/update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is critical that Customer never spents a cent over a limit (there
>   is no human delivering goods that would check limit manually)

Please read this couple of posts: [RC Dont Exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/) and [Eventual Consistency](https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/07/23/DDD-Eventual-Consistency)

If the systems owners still think that the codition must be honored then, to avoid concurrency issues, you could use a precomputed `currentLimitSpent` stored in persistence (because no Event Sourcing Tag in your question) to check the invariant and use it as optimistic concurrency flag.

- Hidrate your aggregate with `currentLimitSpent` and any other data you need from persistence.
- Check rules (`customerMaxCredit <= currentLimitSpent + newTransactionValue`).
- Persist (`currentLimitSpent + newTransactionValue`) as the new `currentLimitSpent`.
- If `currentLimitSpent` has changed in persistence while the aggregate was working (many Users in the same Company making transactions) you should get a optimisticConcurrency error from persistence.
- You could stop on exception or rehidrate the aggregate and try again.

This is a overview. It can not be more detailed without entering into tech stack details and architectural design.

Comment: thanks for your nice explanation! just one clarification, doesn’t this again introduce 2 step, non-transactional edits: one to update `currentLimitSpent` and one to place actual `Transaction`?

Comment: The aggregate checks the currentLimitSpent rule and any other rule to create the Transaction. Its response will be Error or OK. On OK the aggregate response contains all the changing data that need to be persisted to keep the system in a consistent state. This is just one transaction per aggregate. In the persistence side you should have a mechanism that allows you to open a persistence engine transaction-> persist new transaction->persist currentLimitSpent->commit/rollback transaction.

Comment: Try to do not mix the transaction concept of an aggregate (business transaction) with the transaction of a persistence engine.

Comment: yes i see, so it relies on transactional capabilities of persistance technology? thats one of the solutions i had on mind, pretty common, but then i thought thats a bit out of ddd order because it tightly couples 2 aggregates and potentially leaks business rules out of domain. (not sure about this, just stating my impression)

Comment: "because it tightly couples 2 aggregates" may be a indicator that you need to redesign your aggregates...

Comment: i guess that my question - how?:)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243959/how-to-properly-define-an-aggregate-in-ddd/51299995#51299995

Comment: "leaks business rules out of domain" - leaks where? Into persistence layer? The persistence layer just uptade a few columns in a few tables with an "all or nothing" behaviour. There are no business rules there.

Comment: This could help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682746/aggregate-root-invariant-enforcement-with-application-quotas/56700736#56700736

Comment: this last link is somehing i haven’t seen before and its very helpful, thank you!